# Find the probability that Carl arrives first

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> Walter and Carl both often need to travel from Location A to Location B. Walter walks,
>   and his travel time is Normal with mean $w$ minutes and standard deviation $\sigma$ minutes
>   (travel time can’t be negative without using a tachyon beam, but assume that w is so
>   much larger than σ that the chance of a negative travel time is negligible).
>   Carl drives his car, and his travel time is Normal with mean $c$ minutes and standard
>   deviation $2\sigma$ minutes (the standard deviation is larger for Carl due to variability in traffic
>   conditions). Walter’s travel time is independent of Carl’s. On a certain day, Walter and
>   Carl leave from Location A to Location B at the same time.
>
> (a) Find the probability that Carl arrives first (in terms of $\Phi$ and the parameters)
>
> (b) Give a fully simplified criterion (not in terms of $\Phi$), such that Carl has more than a $50%$ chance of arriving first if and only if the criterion is satisfied.
>
> (c) Walter and Carl want to make it to a meeting at Location B that is scheduled to begin $w+10$ minutes after they depart from Location A. Give a fully simplified criterion (not in terms of $\Phi$) such that Carl is more likely than Walter to make it on time for the meeting if and only if the criterion is satisfied.

What I did so far:

$W\sim N(w,\sigma^2)$, $\ \ C\sim N(c,4\sigma^2)$; $\ \ W+C:=Z\sim N(w+c,5\sigma^2)$

a) $P(\min(W,C))=P(W \le t,C \le t)=1-P(W \ge t)P(C \ge t)=1-[1-Φ_w(t)][1-Φ_c(t)]$
Am I going in a right direction and if yes what to do next? Anyone, please? Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

a) $W\sim N(w,\sigma^2),\ \ C\sim N(c,4\sigma^2); \ \ C-W =Z\sim N(c-w,5\sigma^2)$

To find P(C-W < 0)

$P(Z<0)$,  Standardizing Z:

P$\Bigl(\frac{(Z-(c-w))}{(\sqrt5 \sigma)}< \frac{0-(c-w))}{(\sqrt5 \sigma)}\Bigr)$

P$\Bigl(X < \frac{w-c}{\sqrt5 \sigma}\Bigr)$

$\Phi\Bigl(\frac{w-c}{\sqrt5 \sigma}\Bigr)$

For further help, you can check [Carl has more than a 50% chance of arriving first](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2576747/510680)